# Flow Builder won't save Platform Event

Tags: visual-workflow

New issue -- don't know if this is Summer '19 or the New Flow Builder (I suspect Flow Builder).

I have an autolaunched flow that starts by waiting for a Platform event called NewSms__e. Flow builder lets me create the Pause and Wait for event, but I need to store the event and all its data in a Variable of type Record, specifying NewSms__c as the type. I can create the variable, but when I try to select it as the destination for the Platform event, it gives an error saying it's the wrong type.

Anybody else seeing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE. Last night when I posted this, I was trying the same thing on several orgs with the same results.

This morning, I've been successful at doing this. Don't know what changed or what I've done differently. Weird, but no longer an issue for me.